# Related to face recognition and face detection problem?

Tags: opencv

Since i am using localbinarypatterhistogram(LBPH) algorithm for recognition and Haarcascade for face detection purpose.i found that accuracy given by both of arenot upto level that want. so Is there any machine learning algorithmn in python that can detect and recognize images based on trained images and give more accuracy result than LBPH and haarcascade.onetime i try to use dlib library but while installing it . it demand to download microsoft visual studio which I feel boring.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, haar cascade is a legacy technique for face detection and LBPH is a legacy technique for face recognition as well. Deep learning based techniques are state-of-the-art nowadays.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace

models = ['VGG-Face', 'Facenet', 'OpenFace', 'DeepFace', 'DeepID', 'Dlib']
backends = ['opencv', 'ssd', 'dlib', 'mtcnn']

model = 'VGG-Face'
backend = 'mtcnn'

DeepFace.verify("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", model_name = model, detector_backend = backend)
```

All models mentioned above are state-of-the-art models. All backends except opencv are state-of-the-art as well. OpenCV backend uses haar cascade. SSD is a modern face detection technique but face alignment is based on haar cascade in this backend. I recommend you to use VGG-Face / Facenet and MTCNN pair to have the best results.